# Unable to open Video File in Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video

I have installed OpenCV in Windows 7 (32 bit) and Put the `cv2.pyd` file in Python Modules Directory and everything is working just fine but except opening of Video file {I have tried 5-6 different kind of extensions but nothing is helping}
CODE::

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the line `cap.isOpened()` always returns False {i also tried providing absolute path to the video file} but that too return false
So please can please anybody help me that why that line is always returning False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution there is a file present in `C:\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\opencv_ffmpeg.dll` just Copy and Paste that file into your Python base directory say `C:\Python\opencv_ffmpeg.dll` and rename the file to the version of the OpenCV you are using like in my case its v3.0.0 so i have to rename it as `C:\Python\opencv_ffmpeg300.dll`
if your system is X64 then also add _64 at the end like `C:\Python\opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll`

Comment: Worked for me, why don't you mark it as a solution?

Comment: This worked for me also. I didn't need to rename the DLL as the version of OpenCV I downloaded had the DLLs named correctly. Important point is that this goes into the python dir e.g. `C:\Python27` rather than the `DLLs`  directory beneath that. I had to restart the python interpreter as well.

Comment: Are you able to play the sound with the video