# Can't use mobile phone videos in open cv

Tags: python, opencv, video

I can't use videos recorded from phone, in 3gp format, in opencv VideoCapture in Python. It is working fine with webcam recorded .avi videos and some other .avi videos. I even converted the phone recorded videos in .avi format using some converters but it still didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
# extracting some frames from videos

import cv2 
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('mario.avi') #working good with some .avi files

i=0 while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame =cap.read()
    #gray =cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if((i%7)==0):
        cv2.imwrite('mario_'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)
    i+=1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break cap.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: That's because `.3gp` videos are not compatible with OpenCV.  How exactly did you convert the videos to AVI?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to tell that you must be facing this problem not only with mobile videos but with many others, except for those which you must have taken through your own laptop's cam.
This problem can be corrected as follows:
(1) **copy and paste**:
     You must copy 'opencv_ffmpeg300.dll' file which is present at location '\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin' and paste it at C:\Python27. Just this and I had tested it with python 2.7.6 with opencv 3.0.
(2) **edit environmental variables**:
     Add path of the above dll file i.e. '\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin'.
I hope this will work for you as, I faced similar problem and it had worked for me as well.

Comment: thanks it worked ..and yeah you are right it was not working with some other  videos too.

Comment: Linking a similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927839/unable-to-open-video-file-in-python-using-opencv